# beanShell json body for post method on Jmeter

Tags: beanshell

can anyone help to add escape quotation marks with slash like \" on this son body:

```
    {
  "firstName": "teo",
  "lastName": "leo",
  "companyName": "abc",
  "restaurantId": "54d34443e4b0382b3208703d",
  "phones": [
    {
      "label": "Mobile",
      "value": "123456789",
      "countryCode": "+123",
      "isPrimary": true
    }
  ],
  "addresses": "haha"
}
```

i've tried with this one but `beanShell PreProcessor` can't accept it

```
String formvalues = "{\"firstName\": \"teo\",\"lastName\": \"leo\",\"companyName\": \"abc\",\"restaurantId\": \"54d34443e4b0382b3208703d\",\"phones\": [{\"label\":\"Mobile\",\"value\": \"123456789\",\"countryCode\": \"+123\",\"isPrimary\": true}],\"addresses\": \"haha\"}"
```

thanks you so much!

Comment: Then replace `"` with `\"` before passing it to beanShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep formatting:

```
String formvalues = "{\n" +
        "  \"firstName\": \"teo\",\n" +
        "  \"lastName\": \"leo\",\n" +
        "  \"companyName\": \"abc\",\n" +
        "  \"restaurantId\": \"54d34443e4b0382b3208703d\",\n" +
        "  \"phones\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"label\": \"Mobile\",\n" +
        "      \"value\": \"123456789\",\n" +
        "      \"countryCode\": \"+123\",\n" +
        "      \"isPrimary\": true\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ],\n" +
        "  \"addresses\": \"haha\"\n" +
        "}";
```

If you want single line (mind that Content-Length will be different)

```
String formvalues = "{\"firstName\":\"teo\",\"lastName\":\"leo\",\"companyName\":\"abc\",\"restaurantId\":\"54d34443e4b0382b3208703d\",\"phones\":[{\"label\":\"Mobile\",\"value\":\"123456789\",\"countryCode\":\"+123\",\"isPrimary\":true}],\"addresses\":\"haha\"}";
```

---

Full code to generate the body and add it as parameter:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

String formvalues = "{\n" +
           "  \"firstName\": \"teo\",\n" +
           "  \"lastName\": \"leo\",\n" +
           "  \"companyName\": \"abc\",\n" +
           "  \"restaurantId\": \"54d34443e4b0382b3208703d\",\n" +
           "  \"phones\": [\n" +
           "    {\n" +
           "      \"label\": \"Mobile\",\n" +
           "      \"value\": \"123456789\",\n" +
           "      \"countryCode\": \"+123\",\n" +
           "      \"isPrimary\": true\n" +
           "    }\n" +
           "  ],\n" +
           "  \"addresses\": \"haha\"\n" +
           "}";

Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
arguments.addArgument(new HTTPArgument("",formvalues));       
sampler.setArguments(arguments);
```

JavaDoc on relevant classes:

- [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html)
- [HTTPArgument](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/HTTPArgument.html)
- [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) (shorthand for `sampler`)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: wow, thanks you so much, i've generated the right json body for http post method with _"If you want single line (mind that Content-Length will be different)"_
will try other which you suggest :D